# Как получить значение полей из подстановочной таблицы

Tags: ado, delphi

`ADOTableТовар` используется в `ADOTableНакладная` в качестве подстановочной таблицы. Как в накладной получить не только выбираемое поле названия товара, но и цену товара?

Пытаюсь использовать метод

```
OnCalcFields и Calculated поле: ADOTableНакладнаяЦенаТовара.Value:=ADOTableТоварЦена.Value
```

Цена берется только из первой записи товаров. Устанавливаю Товары, как мастер таблицу для Накладной - пропадает сама возможность `lookup` - остается только текущее название. Неужели делать поле Цена тоже подстановочным?

Answer (score 1):

Надо не значение поля получать из подстановочной таблицы, а при подстановке сформировать новое поле, как совокупность интересующих (например, сцепить как строки), и уже эту совокупность выводить в список подстановки.